# Keep a key pressed event, vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there any way to keep Doing something while a key (mouse key) is kept pressed in vba?

```
%' As if there were for example a MouseLeftClicked vba function
Do While MouseLeftClicked 
Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Rotation = Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Rotation + 15
DoEvents
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but you'll need to capture the mouse clicks in a UserForm as below:

In your UserForm

```
Private Sub UserForm_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    booKeyPressed = True
    RotateIt

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    booKeyPressed = False

End Sub
```

In a Module

```
Public booKeyPressed As Boolean

Function RotateIt()

    If Not booKeyPressed Then Exit Function
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "RotateIt"
    Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Rotation = Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Rotation + 15
    DoEvents

End Function
```

The above code will rotate your picture every 1 second so long as the mouse is clicked on your Userform. You can change this to be a specific control and you can also change the time interval should you need to.

There's no way I know of to capture the MouseClick event on a worksheet, but you could link it to a worksheet event if that better suits your needs.

Your question mentions key press, but your sample code mentions mouse. You can easily adapt to which ever you need because both are available as Userform events

Comment: Thanks. Actually doesn't matter mouse click or a key, you say if I use a key instead of mouse, I can adapt it even from worksheet? Because this is what I need, command from worksheet.

Comment: No, only in a Userform. Sorry

Comment: If you put a button or other control on the worksheet, you could capture its event. But not the worksheet itself. If you do decide to do this, the code will be the same except it would be YourButton_MouseDown instead of UserForm_MouseDown